# Streamplot of a 3D vector field

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I have a 3-dimensional vector field, i.e., `x`, `y`, `z` arrays of length `N` and `u`, `v`, `w` arrays of shape `N x N x N`.

I want to get streamline coordinates in the fashion it's done in `matplotlib.pyplot.streamplot`. I tried rewriting the original module functions to generalize for 3d case, but it's not working properly.

Is there a cleaner and faster way of doing this?

**PS.** I really don't need to plot the data, so I don't need a bunch of vectors, just the coordinates of streamlines.